# Numbers exceeded from a table

Tags: tables, elsarticle

I use "elsarticle" class and I want to create a table but the last columns exceed from boundary of table.

```
 \documentclass[review]{elsarticle}

 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}

\begin{table*}
    \caption{some words }
        \label{table1}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l*{12}{C}c@{}}
        \toprule
        Datasets     & a & b & c & d & e & f & g& h & i & j &k & l \\ 
        \midrule
        a   & 0.7291      & 0.0.7499          & 0.7499   & 0.7326  & 0.7499    & 0.7499   & 0.4726    & 0.7499     & 0.7499    & 0.7499 & 0.7499 & 0.7499\\ 
        
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{table*}
```

How it can be fixed.

[image]

Errors related to the first answer of @Zarko :
[image]

Comment: As always on the site, please provide a full, but minimal self contained example others can copy and test as is. We cannot du much with sniplets like this. You will hardly ever have enough room for 12 5 digit numbers. Are you sure this is the best way to present your data to the reader? the reader who most likely will never read 12 columns.

Comment: Please also tell us how or where the `C` column type is defined.

Comment: When I use IEEETRAN class, there is no problem but in elsarticle it fails.

Comment: The whole table is a lot wider than the textwidth. It is very likely that you will not be able to fit a 14 column table into the available space.

Comment: @leandriis, how can I fix that?

Comment: Please provide some more information. The definition of the C column type is missing. Also, will you add more rows to the table and if so, what kind of information will they contain? Are the letters in the column header placeholders and if so, what will they be replaced with?

Comment: Do you get any error messages from your code? If so, it might also be helpful to mention, which.

Comment: Regarding of use `table*`, can I conclude, that you have two column document and consequently options for document class should be: `\documentclass[review, twocolumn]{elsarticle}`?

Comment: @Zarko , When I used two column style of ieeetran, I use this table and there was no problem, but at now, I want to use one column elsarticle and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If your document has one column, than possible solution is rounding numbers to three decimal numbers and use `\small` font size:

**Edit:**

- In MWE (Minimal Working Example) are used `S` columns (defined in `\siunitx` package, which is added to your MWE), which enable rounding numbers in cells. For more details about `\siunitx` you can find in its documentation, which is part of your LaTeX installation or it is available on CTAN, for example [here](http://ctan.ijs.si/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf):

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}            % added package, used for S columns
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\caption{some words}
\label{table1}
    \small
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} 
                            l
                      *{12}{S[round-mode=places,
                              round-precision=3,
                              table-format=1.4]} }
    \toprule
Datasets    
    & {a} & {b} & {c} & {d} & {e} & {f} & {g} & {h} & {i} & {j} & {k} & {l}     \\
    \midrule
a   & 0.7291    & 0.7499    & 0.7499    & 0.7326    & 0.7499    & 0.7499   
    & 0.4726    & 0.7499    & 0.7499    & 0.7499    & 0.7499    & 0.7499        \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}    
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

- In the case, that for you all decimal numbers in table are essential, than may be solution to use even smaller font size as is `\footnotesize` and break text in the first column header into two lines. In this case, it makes sense to use a the `makecell` package:

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs, 
            makecell}   % added package
\usepackage{siunitx}    % added package
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\caption{some words}
\label{table1}
    \footnotesize
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                            l
                      *{12}{S[table-format=1.4]} }
    \toprule
\makecell[l]{Data\\[-2ex] sets}
    & {a} & {b} & {c} & {d} & {e} & {f} & {g} & {h} & {i} & {j} & {k} & {l}     \\
    \midrule
a   & 0.7291    & 0.7499    & 0.7499    & 0.7326    & 0.7499    & 0.7499
    & 0.4726    & 0.7499    & 0.7499    & 0.7499    & 0.7499    & 0.7499        \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
    \end{table}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, in your MWE you use `table*` float, which are used in two column document. In this case, it makes sense to use the `makecell`  package

```
\documentclass[review, twocolumn]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}
\caption{some words}
\label{table1}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l*{12}{S[table-format=1.4]} }
    \toprule
Datasets    
    & {a} & {b} & {c} & {d} & {e} & {f} & {g} & {h} & {i} & {j} & {k} & {l}     \\
    \midrule
a   & 0.7291    & 0.7499    & 0.7499    & 0.7326    & 0.7499    & 0.7499   
    & 0.4726    & 0.7499    & 0.7499    & 0.7499    & 0.7499    & 0.7499        \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
    \end{table*}    
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I use one column style and both of your answer still don't work. I add the errors of your first answer.

Comment: @Ben25, My MWE as it is, cannot generate showed errors. In your test you should change something in it.

Comment: You are right. but I just copied all of the first answer and the error changed. I add it to my question.

Comment: @Ben25, you have to old your LaTeX distribution installation. Please upgrade it to the recent version. Also you need to  add package `eso-pic`  to your LaTeX installation.